# PHPS source file - 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Hi I am trying to view a .PHPS source file on Ubuntu 20.04.3 Apache 2.4.41 PHP 7 server but when I view the .phps file in the browser I get this message -

> 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

If I rename the file type to .txt I can view the file fine in the browser.

I’ve added the following to .htaccess -

```
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
        
RewriteRule (.*\.php)s$ $1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
```

And I tried adding that to **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/demo.testsite.com-le-ssl.conf** but it didn’t work.

I then updated this file **/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.3.conf** and commented out **Require all denied** and also added **Order Deny,Allow** and **Deny from all** -

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    #Require all denied
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I then restarted apache **sudo service apache2 restart** and I still get this message in the browser when viewing the PHPS file -

> 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

Has anyone got any idea how to fix?

---

### update 2022/05/15

For some reason I am getting 403 Forbidden again. My only guess why is because I did some updates (sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade). When I checked this file again **/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.3.conf** the setting showed **Require all denied** so I changed it back to **Require all granted**.

I restarted both servives **sudo service apache2 restart** and **sudo service php7.3-fpm restart** and still **403 Forbidden**.

When I search for .phps in the apache2 folder the same result appears in these files -

- /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php7.3-fpm.conf
- /etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.3-fpm.conf
- /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.3.conf

All have this inside -

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    Require all granted
</FilesMatch>

# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
#
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I've tried removing this from all those files but still not working -

```
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache 2.4 has deprecated the `Allow,Deny` syntax. Replace

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

with

```
Require all granted
```

and then restart Apache.

**Edited to add:** Even when you're using the `Allow,Deny` syntax, `Deny from all` without an `Allow` statement later would, as you'd expect, deny all access to the resource in question.

### References

- [Apache 2.4 access control docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html)

Comment: Hi @Pat J please see my new comment from update 2022/05/15!